# Flutter Refactoring move widgets to new files

Tags: flutter, refactoring

I have a DefaultTabController that is getting longer and longer in code. As a beginner, I see I might miss some class / oop knowledge here.

I want to move its children to new files. I already have Widget TabContent1 and Widget TabContent2 in the same class, but how can I move these widgets to new files? The problem is that they both load values of TextEditingControllers on the TabController level. Moving the two Widgets breaks the reference to these TextEditingControllers. How can I refer to those from the newly created classes?

Update: In addition. As suggested by Ivo, I can put all references in the constructor of my new class. But I have a lot of global controllers and variables in the top level class. Also need to bind to the events happening in my new class and have to emit those back or so. It feels more efficient to keep my logic, but only move some of it to sub-classes or so. I feel like the solution should be more in oop/class logic, implementing or extending them

Comment: pass the reference to them

Comment: Can you please explain, or give an example? This would really help me as a beginner. Does this mean putting the references through the constructor?

Comment: yes that's what I mean. Like TabContent1(textEditingController) for example

Comment: I see, but is this the most efficient? What if I have 20 controllers in the end? Is there no way of making my new class 'part' of the first class, so the references keep alive? I feel I'm close with extending classes  or implementing classes but I don't get there.

Comment: It's hard to judge without seeing your code. Why does this TabContent1 need this controller? If it's the only component using it it should just be created in it. not passed to it

Comment: A Text() in TabContent2 displays the value of a TextField in TabContent1, therefore I reside the controller on the level of the DefaultTabController

Comment: I see. Instead of passing them you might also make the TextEditingControllers static maybe, but not sure if that's a good idea

Comment: I see. I'm still looking for the best way to use a lot of nesting widgets that exchange data, not having one huge nested file, but with references to each other like children:[oneInohterfile, anohterinanotherfile]